# S3 Api object storage account validation issue

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to get auth token for creating storage

Storage type id is 24 (S3 API)

I am providing a valid username value for 'X-Auth-User'.

headers = {
    'X-Auth-User': 'xyz:xyz',
    'X-Auth-Key': API_KEY,
}

auth_token_resp = requests.get('https://mon01.objectstorage.softlayer.net/auth/v1.0', headers=headers)

'

## Unauthorized

This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document you requested.

'

This same api is working for Swift Api with different username.

Kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

first at all to work with S3 is not the same as to work with swift, using S3 the enpoints are differents and also the connection is different I suggest you to see documentation first:

https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/crs-endpoints.html

this is the part about authentication:

https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/crs-authentication.html

Regards